# Is there a way to restrict objects parameters according to a derived class range of possibility values?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make an animal database. How can I make each animal species have some parameters with fixed values and some with a range of possible values so individuals (objects) from each species can "choose" from?

From basic OOP, I could have a class Dog, with objects "Rex" and "Fido", and then a class Bird, with objects "Rocky" and "Coco". I created a base class for them, class Animal, with parameters common for all, as shown below.

When I create the class Dog, how can I fix the Body_Parts I want all dogs to have (all dogs have head, legs, tails, etc, but no wings) and how can I set a range of possible values for each object of class Dog to pick from (as dogs may be black, brown or white, maybe a mix of both, but never green nor blue)?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class Body_Part
{
    HEAD,
    WING,
    ...,
    TAIL;
};

enum class Color
{
    BLACK,
    RED,
    WHITE,
    BROWN,
    GREEN
    BLUE;
};

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();

private:
    std::string m_Species;
    std::vector<Body_Part> m_Limbs;
    std::vector<Color> m_Colors;
}
```

Comment: Why not use arrays/vectors of strings?  Yeah, they take more space but unless you're on embedded hardware you'll never notice it and it allows you to have infinite flexibility.

Comment: I changed the "arrays" to std::vector to avoid confusion. Still with strings, instead of enum classes, I would like to restrict the objects from derived classes from picking any color or body part they want.

Comment: _"how can I fix the Body_Parts I want all dogs to have"_: easy, in `Dog::Dog()`. _"how can I set a range of possible values for each object of class Dog to pick from"_: unclear, please expand on what you expect.

Comment: Do you want to also model requirements such as "only unicorns with wings can be blue"? Or is this list fixed per child class?

Comment: @Werneck Well, the body parts should't be something the user has any control over, besides possible the quantity.  You have have a map of `<string, int>` and then the user can control how many legs/eyes/wings the object has, but not be able to change what attributes it is built from.

Comment: @YSC In `Dog::Dog()`, but how?
For the second question, I made up the enum class "Color" as example. I have possible Colors for animals in general. Then, for dogs specifically, I'd like to restrict them to choose between valid values, with "GREEN" and "BLUE" being invalid, as there are no dogs with these colors, for example.

Comment: You might want to think a little more about the design of your project. Are you supposed to be able to create an `Animal` instance? Or only e.g. `Cat` or `Dog` instances? Then make sure that no-one can create instances of the `Animal` class (make the constructor protected) and just initialize the color and body-parts in the sub-classes `Cat` or `Dog`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Not mentioned in the example above, as I didn't make that far, but eventually that will happen. I would like to have an Action class or enum class, and for "FLYING", for example, only animals with wings would be able to do that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll take a look on maps for that, as I've never used maps for this specific purpose. I imagine the string would hold the "body part" and the int is user-given for quantity. Is there anyway to make the quantity only changeable for body_parts that the animal actually has (I don't want users giving dogs 6 wings =P). Thanks fo the input.

Comment: You can populate the map with default values, and then let the user be able to change those values like `std::map<std::string, int> body_parts{{"legs", 4},{"eyes",2}.{"ears",2}, ...}`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Didn't think about it, wiil protect Animal. Thanks! Also, even initializing colors and body_parts in the subclasses, how would I go about restricting them only to possible values? Or should I create a vector of Colors in each animal subclass separately?

Comment: I believe you need a vector of allowed colors/body parts as a static const member of each AnimalSpecies class (Dog, Bird, Octopus etc). Then, whenever you set a color of a specific animal (Rex), you need to check whether the value is in this static vector of the corresponding species class (Dog), possibly throw an error otherwise. (or alternatively you use a list of forbidden parts, it might be less typing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, what I'm trying is not actually needed. After talking to a friend, he said that, as I'm doing a **database**, it's all done in the user interface and I don't need a class, with subclasses of it. He said I'm going to create a simple class for each "class and subclass" only for getting user input and recording to file. The restrictions should be added when loading information on screen to the user.

Using the examples above, I would have dog and bird data in a file like, thinking in a txt-like file:

```
(animal,body1-body2-...-bodyN,color1-color2-...-colorN)
```

or

```
(dog,head-teeth-tail,black-brown-white)
(bird,head-beak-wing-tail,black-white-yellow-green-red)
```

And when I try to add a "dog object", like "Fido", only dog information would be available on screen, and so "Fido" would be recorded as:

```
(Fido,head-teeth-tail,black)
```

That way I need to create a class for each animal species, and then another class for input on individuals of each species, with constraints added to the user, and not to the classes.
Thanks everyone, it was all helpful anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(std::vector<Color> allowedColors, std::vector<BodyPart> requiredLimbs)
      : m_Limbs(requiredLimbs), m_colors(allowedColors)
    {}
// ...
};
```

Then each derived class has to decide at construction time what is allowed and what is not.

However, there are several confusions in this code that probably require a different design altogether.

- An animal instance ("Rocky") can have several limbs but only one color (I assume?). So why does every instance of `Animal` have a list of colors?
- Is it supposed to be the job of the `Animal` base class or of each derived class to assign/provide limbs and colors? Who is the user of this code and what are they expected to do? Set limbs and colors? If so, should this be an `Animal` interface or should each `Dog` have a method to decide on its own color?
- Limbs are a "required" list (each instance of a given animal type needs to have *all* those limbs), but the color is an "allowed" list (each instance of a given animal type needs to have *exactly one* of those colors). That's a pretty significant difference in meaning that is currently unreflected in the code.
- But then the question becomes what "having" a given limb means. Is a `Unicorn` complete because its `m_Limb` list contains two `WING`s? How does this help if every unicorn needs to have that? Does the `m_Limb` list say *anything* about the animal instance or does it actually just describe the *kind* of animal?
- In my eyes, the list of required limbs and allowed colors should not be stored in each animal instance but should be some property of the *derived type* (e.g. `Dog`, `Horse`). When you want to infuse *types* with properties you tend to leave OOP land and enter template land...

Comment: 1. "Rocky" would be a Bird instance, which is derived from animal. Birds have fixed body parts: 2 wings, 2 eyes, 1 tail, etc; they may have multiple colors.

Comment: 2. I thought of the Animal class as a provider of all possibilities for each subclass, but only for things all animals would have (like colors, despite what color or colors are possible for each specific animal). Limbs wouldn't be set, they are fixed to each animal. Colors could be changed for each individual for each species, but only those possible to that species (dogs could be brown, white or both; never blue).

Comment: 3. I don't know how I could reflect that difference in my code. Also, color as an allowed list allow animals to choose multiple colors, provided they are allowed for that species.
4. Also, I don't really care about quantity of body parts, only if they have that part. I believe the animal features simply describe the animal, but I'm not sure what you asked there, sorry. If every unicorn has a wing "body part" and dogs don't, unicorns can fly and dogs can't. It's descriptive, I think. Not sure.
5. I'll check templates, as you may have reached the "better way of doing" part of the problem.